# iOS - Detect movie is finished

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play a movie , I create a method which should detects when movie is finished then run a method :

```
- (void)movieFinishedWithSelector:(SEL)selectors {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(selectors)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:[player moviePlayer]];
  }
```

and use this method like this , but does not work .

```
[self movieFinishedWithSelector:@selector(finished)];
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

The `selectors` parameter is already a selector. Don't use `@selector`:

```
- (void)movieFinishedWithSelector:(SEL)selector {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:selector
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:[player moviePlayer]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! but still nothing happens !!

Answer (score 2):

create a notication when you load the movie

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:movieController];
```

When finished the myMovieFinished will be called

```
-(void)myMovieFinished:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"%@",aNotification.userInfo);
   int reason =    [[[aNotification userInfo]valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification]intValue];
    if (reason==MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Movie finished playing");
    }
    else if (reason==MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited)
    {
        NSLog(@"Movie finished because user exited");
    }
    else if (reason==MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError)
    {
        NSLog(@"movie finished playback error");
    }

    movieController=[aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:movieController ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

how did you define the selector? It should be:

```
- (void)movieDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
```